# I need to make the triangle turn to the right

Tags: java

Ok so This code makes the triangle point up but i need to make it point to the right please help

```
public void five_a_pointUp (int num)
{
    System.out.print('\f');
    for (int x=1; x<=num; x += 2)
    {
        for (int y=0; y <= ((num - x)/2); y++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int z=0; z<x; z++)
        {
           System.out.print("#");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I have tried this code but it ends in an infinite loop

```
{
    System.out.print('\f');
    for(int x=1; x<=num;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<=x; x++)
        {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried, or what specifically is confusing you?

Comment: Try to write this triangle on paper. Start from top-left corner. What steps do you need to make?

Comment: I am confused about how to make it point to the right i have tried other codes but most have ended up in infinite loops please help me its due today

Comment: re "its due today": you would be wise not to state this in your posts/comments. Even if it is urgent to you, realize that it is not urgent to us. Many here take offense to this as it implies to them that a) the poster thinks that his post is more important than everyone else's (and it isn't since all questions here are equally important), and b) that the poster wants to put pressure on the volunteers who come here to help on their own free time.

Comment: i am really sorry you are right i am new here it wont happen again

Comment: You always have 5 minutes to edit your comments, so do so and remove that part from it.

Comment: oh i didnt know that i am truly sorry but i wasnt quick enough

Comment: You are incrementing x in the second for statement maybe you meant to increment y instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is homework I can't give you working code but you should manage to do fine with pseducodoce. So lets start.

Try splitting this problem into smaller ones. For instance if we want to print triangle like this

```
#
##
###
####
###
##
#
```

lets try to create code which will print

```
#
##
###
####
```

and when it is done, lest add code which will print

```
###
##
#
```

So our code can be divided into two methods like:

```
printUpperPart(n);
printLowerPart(n-1);//notice size of lower part compared to upper one
```

Lets focus on our upper part for now. What do we need here?

- loop which will be responsible for invoking printing 4 lines,
- and in that loop we need to print appropriate number of `#` so we need another loop for that.

so our code can look like

```
for (line in 1..n)
  for (hashPosition in 1..line)
    print one hash
  move to next line
```

Now try to implement it and based on that try to figure out code for lower part.

Comment: Ok i coded the first half for(int x=1; x<=num;x++)
     {
         System.out.println(" ");
         for(int y=1; y<=x; y++)
         {
             System.out.print("#");
         }
     }

Comment: You could do it even with one loop but your code would be very ugly. I posted solution which would be easy to read and write.